# Default Dropdown Option PropertyPaneDropdown SelectedKey Not Working

Tags: dropdown, spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm working with the RC0 version of spfx and am having trouble selecting a default dropdown option.

I'm using the selectedKey property that I found in the documentation [here.](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/reference/spfx/sp-webpart-base/ipropertypanedropdownprops.md) I have used both text and integer keys.

```
  PropertyPaneDropdown('test2', {
            label: 'Dropdown',
            options: [
              { key: '1', text: 'One'},
              { key: '2', text: 'Two' },
              { key: '3', text: 'Three' },
              { key: '4', text: 'Four'}
            ],
            selectedKey: '4',
        })
```

When I inspect the react state and props on initial render here is what I get. Notice selectedKey is not present.

[image: On initial render before I select an option]

After I select an option selectedKey and selectedIndex appear and are changed respectively.

[image: selectedKey shows up.]

**EDIT FYI**

I also tried the method that Chris O'Brian used [here](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2016/09/sharepoint-framework-web-part-properties-pages-groups-controls.html) that involves setting the default like so...

```
PropertyPaneDropdown('dropdownProperty', { 
              label: 'This is the label', 
              isDisabled: false, 
              options: [ 
                { key: 'Red', text: 'Red' }, 
                { key: 'Green', text: 'Green' }, 
                { key: 'DarkBlue', text: 'Dark blue', **isSelected: true** } 
              ] 
            })
```

This method wouldn't even transpile the typescript.

Comment: Please note that the dropdown I have in the code is straight from the first demo.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct - this is a bug.  The problem is that the SelectedKey  being passed in is currently being ignored, and instead the control is looking for the key with the value of the control property (this.properties.dropdownProperty in your case)

As a workaround, what you could do something like

```
if ( !this.properties.test2)
{
    this.properties.test2= '4';
}
```

I've added an issue here to track this - https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/366
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your manifest.json for your clientside webpart under
preconfiguredEntires --> properties, add your PropertyPaneControl Name with the default property value
"properties": {
      "test2": "4"
}